# How to determinine the convergence/absolute convergence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^px}{1+x^q}dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^px}{1+x^q}dx$?

If $q\leq 0$, the Cauchy implies divergence.

If $q>1$, then $|\cdots|\leq \frac{1}{x^q}$, and the absolute convgence.

What about $0<q<1$? The terrible $\sin^px$, not $\sin (x^p)$...how to do?

Comment: What's about the definition for "$p$"? I don't see the definition about $p$ in the problem. I think it's important because $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{1+x^{1/2}}\, {\rm d}x$ conveges but $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{2} x}{1+x^{1/2}}\, {\rm d}x$ doesn't converges.

Comment: @user1027216 Year. It seems very difficult to relate the convergence with $p\in\Bbb R$.